# (MySQL e PHP) Como eu poderia fazer condições para isso caso não tenha brindes com uma pontuação maior em estoque pegue um brinde de pontuação menor?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação que ela funciona da seguinte forma

Na Administração constam formulário para cadastro de BRINDES (tipo chaveiro, boné e outros) mas e cada um deles tem uma **pontuação** *(Já explico porque a pontuação)*

Também tem um formulário pra cadastro de produtos que a empresa tem pra vender (tipo uma escada de ferro, uma bola de vôlei ou qualquer outro) e cada um tem um valor de **PONTUAÇÃO** também.

O porque das pontuações de brindes e produtos?

Bom o cliente vai participar de uma feira e os visitantes da feira vão ver um site para acessar e preencher um formulário pra captura de leads e informar se já são clientes, quais produtos a empresa comercializa e outras coisas mais, dependendo das respostas e produtos selecionados nesse formulário que o visitante vai preencher se fechar a pontuação igual ou maior que a de um determinado brinde ele ganha ele.

Mas ai que entra a minha questão:

Abaixo eu tenho um select que faço pra determinar qual brinde o sistema vai apresentar para o visitante da feira.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM brindes 
WHERE Status_Brinde = '1' 
AND Quantidade_Brinde > 0 
AND Pontos_Brinde >= 400 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

Mas digamos que ele (visitante da feira) não tenha conseguido uma pontuação maior que 400 quando ele preenche o formulário, no momento ele não exibe nenhum brinde na tela.

Como eu poderia fazer condições para isso caso não tenha brindes com uma pontuação maior em estoque pegue um brinde de pontuação menor?

Comment: tentou usar [`case`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp), man?

Comment: Até li algo sobre mas não entendi direito ainda como funciona o CASE

Comment: Não limite o valor do brinde , ordene pelo valor descendete e continue limitando a um.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pontos_brinde, status_brinde
FROM brindes
WHERE Status_Brinde = '1' 
AND Quantidade_Brinde > 0  
(CASE
        WHEN pontos_brinde >= 400 THEN 'Parabéns você atingiu a pontuação, vamos pegar o brinde'
        else pontos_brinde < 400 THEN 'Você não atingiu a pontuação, mas ainda sim recebera um brinde'
end); 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

Acho que seria algo próximo a isso, talvez tenha um erro ou outro pois não criei as tabelas e etc, mas só moldar, nessa situação é case mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Então pessoal a principio resolvi aqui depois de pensar um pouco ontem a noite sobre o caso

```
SELECT * 
FROM brindes 
WHERE Status_Brinde = '1' 
AND Quantidade_Brinde > 0 
AND (Pontos_Brinde >= 400 OR Pontos_Brinde >= 1 )
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

Adicionei um OR na consulta dai ele me trás brindes abaixo da pontuação caso os com maior pontuação não tenha mais em estoque.